# Print word before matching a pattern

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to print only first word after a matching pattern but not getting success, let me explain to you what is my requirement

**Input file**

```
 $>cat abc.txt
    source: hrs1bdapoc2:21002
            1571426725 secs (436507.42 hrs) behind the primary
```

**Desired Output:-**

```
echo $delay_time
1571426725
```

**What I have tried using awk command till now:-**

```
$>delay_time=`awk -F'secs' '{print $1}' abc.txt`
$>echo $delay_time
source: hrs1bdapoc2:21002 1571426725
```

Can you let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: You haven't shown everything so this doesn't tie together to make sense. 1) You haven't shown where you set `rep_monitor`. 2) You're echoing a different variable, `rep_time_diff1`, than the one you set, `delay_time`. Please fix these issues and **show everything** please.

Comment: Thanks, @JeffY I can't use the prod variable thats why this mismatch happened I had edited my question, thanks to showing the problem in my question.

Comment: There's nothing like `rep_monitor=``cat abc.txt``` in there?

Comment: @Abhinav, Could you please check my solution once and let me know if that helped you?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Though I suspect about your Input_file because code you showed should work out.

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+ secs/){print substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)}' Input_file
```

Also check your Input_file if it has control M characters by doing `cat -v Input_file` if yes then you could remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file`

Also to create a variable do something like `var=$(above command)`

Answer (score 0):

Print the first element on the line that has `secs`

```
delay_time=$(awk '/secs/{ print $1 }' abc.txt)
```

Using backticks ` is discouraged. Use `$( ... )` for command substitution instead.